# how to loop a tkinter label using indexes from a list

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make my quiz game as a gui, I made it without one. I tried looking all over the internet. I've been trying to find a way to make it work in tkinter but its so confusing. Also I am really motivated about finding a solution but its been 3 days already and I couldn't find one.

I will try to explain more, so basically I couldn't make my quiz game work using tkinter, I tried to make a loop so I don't have to make labels over and over again, It will take so much time and its not that efficient. Would you please help me out.

**This is my code without the gui**

```
class Question:
    def __init__(self,prompt,answer, answer2):
        self.answer = answer
        self.prompt = prompt
        self.answer2 = answer2


question_prompts = [
    "When did Tunisia gain independence? \n 1956 , 1984  , 1965 \n", "What is the captial of tunis ? \n Tunis, Gafsa, Nabuel \n",
    "Who won 2018 football world cup ? \n Italy, France, England \n","how long is the eiffel tower ?\n 324m, 354m, 412m \n",
    "What is the heaviest metal \n Iron, Copper, Uraniam \n "
]

questions = [
    Question(question_prompts[0], "1956","1956"),
    Question(question_prompts[1], "Tunis","tunis"),
    Question(question_prompts[2], "France","france"),
    Question(question_prompts[3], "324m","324"),
    Question(question_prompts[4], "Uraniam","uraniam")
]

def playgame():
    score = 0
    for question in questions:
        answer = input(question.prompt)
        if answer == question.answer:
            score += 1
        elif answer == question.answer2:
            score += 1
    print("You have answerd " + str(score) + " / " + str(len(questions)) + " Correct answers ")

playgame()
```

**This is my quiz with gui but its buggy**

```
import tkinter as tk
from time import sleep

win = tk.Tk()

win.title("Learning game")

class Question:
    def __init__(self,prompt,answer, answer2):
        self.answer = answer
        self.prompt = prompt
        self.answer2 = answer2


question_prompts = [
    "When did Tunisia gain independence? \n 1956 , 1984  , 1965 \n", "What is the captial of tunis ? \n Tunis, Gafsa, Nabuel \n",
    "Who won 2018 football world cup ? \n Italy, France, England \n","how long is the eiffel tower ?\n 324m, 354m, 412m \n",
    "What is the heaviest metal \n Iron, Copper, Uraniam \n "
]

questions = [
    Question(question_prompts[0], "1956","1956"),
    Question(question_prompts[1], "Tunis","tunis"),
    Question(question_prompts[2], "France","france"),
    Question(question_prompts[3], "324m","324"),
    Question(question_prompts[4], "Uraniam","uraniam")
]

s = tk.StringVar()
useranwser = tk.StringVar() 

def ask():
    for questionpop in questions:
        s.set(question_prompts.pop(0))


for question in questions:
    q = tk.Label(win)
    q.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    q.config(textvariable = s)
    u_answer = tk.Entry(win, textvariable = useranwser)
    u_answer.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    b = tk.Button(win, text ="Submit", command = ask)
    b.grid(row = 2, column =0 ) 
    
score = 0
if useranwser == question.answer:
    print("Correct")
    score += 1
else:
    print("Uncorrect")


    


ask()
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Dear BackpainYT, how can we help if we do not know what your problem is? Please edit your question to include a description of what is not working.

Comment: The list is empty because you are calling the function initially with `ask()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of things that need changes. Refer to the code below

```py
import tkinter as tk
from time import sleep

win = tk.Tk()

win.title("Learning game")

class Question:
    def __init__(self,prompt,answer, answer2):
        self.answer = answer
        self.prompt = prompt
        self.answer2 = answer2

def ask():
    global score
    print(len(questions))
    if questions:
        #Check both the possible answers
        if useranwser.get() in (questions[0].answer,questions[0].answer2):
            print("Correct")
            score += 1
        else:
            print("Incorrect")
        questions.pop(0)
        if questions:
            s.set(questions[0].prompt) 
        useranwser.set('')
    else:
        print('Done')

question_prompts = [
    "When did Tunisia gain independence? \n 1956 , 1984  , 1965 \n", "What is the captial of tunis ? \n Tunis, Gafsa, Nabuel \n",
    "Who won 2018 football world cup ? \n Italy, France, England \n","how long is the eiffel tower ?\n 324m, 354m, 412m \n",
    "What is the heaviest metal \n Iron, Copper, Uraniam \n "
]

questions = [
    Question(question_prompts[4], "Uraniam","uraniam"),
    Question(question_prompts[0], "1956","1956"),
    Question(question_prompts[1], "Tunis","tunis"),
    Question(question_prompts[2], "France","france"),
    Question(question_prompts[3], "324m","324")
]

s = tk.StringVar()
useranwser = tk.StringVar() 
q = tk.Label(win,textvariable = s)
q.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
u_answer = tk.Entry(win, textvariable = useranwser)
u_answer.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
b = tk.Button(win, text ="Submit", command = ask)
b.grid(row = 2, column =0 ) 

s.set(questions[0].prompt) #Set the initial question 
    
score = 0

win.mainloop()
```

**NOTES**

- `useranwser` is holding the instance of `StringVar()`, use the `.get()` method on it to get the value.
- There is no point in having `for question in questions:` loop as it would do the same thing over and over again.
- `for questionpop in questions:` this loop will clear your list as soon as you call `ask` and since you had done that on program initialization, your list had become empty to begin with.
- In your initial code, the `score` would always remain `0`, firstly because the condition will always be `False` and even if you made the condition right using `.get()` it wouldn't work as you are just performing it once on the program initialization. I have added the corrected condition to the `ask` function so that it it checked every time the `submit` button is clicked.
- `question.answer` only stores a constant value `"Uranium"` as after the iteration in the code above that, it takes the last element of the list.

**EDIT**

> There is a bug that i couldn't fix in your code, I've read and understood your notes and also the code. I kept trying to fix a problem. The last question gets repeated twice

The question wasn't repeated, it took an extra click for the program to print done, since before that `if questions:` was `True` and became `False` after that additional click. Make the changes below and it should work.

```py
def ask():
    global score
    if questions:
        #Check both the possible answers
        if useranwser.get() in (questions[0].answer,questions[0].answer2):
            print("Correct")
            score += 1
        else:
            print("Incorrect")
        questions.pop(0)
        if questions:
            s.set(questions[0].prompt) 
        else:
            print('Done')
            quit() #optional
        useranwser.set('')
```

Comment: There is a bug that i couldn't fix in your code, I've read and understood your notes and also the code.
I kept trying to fix a problem. The last question gets repeated twice

Comment: @BackpainYT I have updated the answer with the code and reason, hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your time, I truly appreciate it man.